# How to install Laravel using Ansible

Tags: laravel, ansible

[playbook error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFCXa.png)I need help n installing laravel using Ansible.

I tried using the document.
https://www.linuxtechi.com/use-ansible-galaxy-roles-ansible-playbook/

But unsuccesful.
[playbook ][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZTkF.png)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

please provide more info with your yml file, error info.. 
also, have you tried this https://dev-yakuza.github.io/en/environment/ansible-laravel/

Comment: cat laravel.yml
---
 - name: Configure Laravel
   become: true
   become_user: root

   hosts: ec2-user@13.58.125.40

   roles:
   - juwai.laravel

Comment: PLAY [Configure Laravel] ****
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******
ok: [ec2-user@13.58.125.40]
TASK [retr0h.logrotate : Install logrotate via apt] *************************************************************************************
skipping: [ec2-user@13.58.125.40]
ok: [ec2-user@13.58.125.40]
TASK [juwai.laravel : Install nginx configuration] ****
fatal: [ec2-user@13.58.125.40]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'env' is undefined"}

PLAY RECAP ***
ec2-user@13.58.125.40      : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=1    rescued=0   ignored=0

Comment: please update your question with yml file & error info for better visibility.